# How to change an onEdit function to work whenever a script runs? - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written an onEdit function, which creates a dropdown list which changes depending on the adjacent value entered into column G of the same row.

The code is:

```
function onEdit() {

var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();;
var OEsheet = ss.getSheetByName("OE names");
var SOsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales Order");
var activeCell = SOsheet.getActiveCell();

if(activeCell.getColumn() == 7 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == "Sales Order") {

  activeCell.offset(0, -6).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

  var OEnames = OEsheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, OEsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var OEnamesIndex = OEnames[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

  if(OEnamesIndex != 0){
 var validationRange = OEsheet.getRange(2, OEnamesIndex, OEsheet.getLastRow());
 var validationRule = app.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();

  activeCell.offset(0, -6).setDataValidation(validationRule);

}
}
}
```

This script works perfectly, but the problem is the data added to column G for my spreadsheet will be added by a script, not manually so I have opted to merge this function with another function so it triggers the creation of the data validation for the whole of Column A when the previous script is triggered, rather than on a manual edit. Therefore, I changed the code to this (which I will merge with a previous function):

```
function DropDowns() {

var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();;
var OEsheet = ss.getSheetByName("OE names");
var SOsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales Order");
var DDcolumn = SOsheet.getRange("A2:A");
var Bcolumn = SOsheet.getRange("G2:G");

  Bcolumn.clearContent().clearDataValidations();

  var OEnames = OEsheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, OEsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var OEnamesIndex = OEnames[0].indexOf(Bcolumn.getValue()) + 1;

  if(OEnamesIndex != 0){
 var validationRange = OEsheet.getRange(2, OEnamesIndex, OEsheet.getLastRow());
 var validationRule = app.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();

 DDcolumn.setDataValidation(validationRule);

}
  }
```

However, this does not work properly - it creates a data validation for the whole column (which is what I wanted), but it does not use the value in the adjacent column of the same row to create this data validation (because I had to remove the activeCell functionality as the data will not be manually entered I think). It now seems to be using only Column A in the OE names sheet to create the data validation for the row, rather than the column in the OE sheet which corresponds to the value in column G of the Sales Orders sheet.

This is a link to a copy of my spreadsheet with all the irrelevant scripts and data removed: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bligSkSDr0dtU3Zwj1c-SasvKbHqX-QhbM8zysIvM-Q/edit?usp=sharing

How can I fix this so that the script runs and adds dropdown lists to the whole column, but the content of these lists still change depending on the adjacent value in column G?

Thank you

Comment: Can you change your Sheet permissions to Edit? Otherwise we can't see the script. Keep in mind that Simple Triggers like onEdit() [can't be triggered by a script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions).

Comment: It is on edit now, and yes that is why I am having to change the onEdit() to something else but I can't seem to make it work properly

Comment: It's not just Simple triggers that have this limitation. Installable triggers have the [same limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) - "Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. "

Comment: I don't understand why does it have to be a dropdown menu. Why not just copy the value from the G column? Does the dropdown menu include all the values of G?